# Vários itens da Central de Ajuda estão com o título em inglês

Tags: bug, status-aceito, tradução, internacionalização

Embora todos os textos da [central de ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) estejam em português, alguns títulos ainda não foram traduzidos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Verifiquei os demais itens ("Veja mais"), mas não encontrei nenhum outro faltando tradução. A lista completa de itens com título a traduzir é, portanto:

- [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)
- [How do I search?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)
- [Why is voting important?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
- [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)
- [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Comment: Por uma série de questões técnicas, a tradução desses títulos só pode ser feita por devs. Entre a mudança de data center e uma conferência em Oslo, essa semana não tem muita gente pra fazer isso. Semana que vem damos um jeito nisso.

Comment: @Gabe Eu acabei de "descobrir" a mesma coisa e achei essa pergunta. O problema persiste, e inclusive algumas perguntas que estavam traduzidas estão agora em inglês (How do I write a good answer?). Há alguma coisa que possamos fazer? Outro ponto que seria interessante corrigir são as screenshots da Ajuda, como essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: @Molx Os screenshots são um problema, e quem quiser ajudar pode postar imagens alternativas no Meta. Quanto aos títulos, quero traduzir todos ainda esse mês, assim que possível. Infelizmente, essa é uma parte que só eu posso fazer

Comment: @Gabe Estava formulando uma pergunta com este mesmo problema, quando o excelente mecanismo do SO sugeriu esta. A tradução ainda não foi feita.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Traduções de páginas e links da "Central de Ajuda"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/tradu%c3%a7%c3%b5es-de-p%c3%a1ginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda)