# Traduções de páginas e links da "Central de Ajuda"

Tags: bug, tradução

Navegando na central de ajuda, notei que algumas páginas possuem os textos sem tradução, apesar das páginas em si estarem traduzidas, mas há também algumas páginas inteiras em inglês. Segue abaixo as que identifiquei:

## Páginas sem tradução:

[<s>How do I report harassment?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6864/28595)

[<s>The Community user deleted my question! What gives?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6876/28595)

[<s>What does "beta" mean?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6878/28595)

[<s>How to not be a spammer</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6884/28595)

[<s>What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6882/28595)

[<s>Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6877/28595)

[How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta)

[<s>What is a locked post?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) => [**Texto traduzido**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6935/28595)

[I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

[Moderator Agreement policies](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mod-agreement-policies)

[Who are the staff, and what is their role here?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

[What are DMCA Takedowns and why was my contribution removed?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dmca-takedown)

[When does Stack Exchange ask for my cookie consent?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/cookie-reconsent)

[How do I use Saves?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/saves)

[How do I use the First answers queue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers)

[How do I use the First questions queue?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions)

## Páginas apenas com o texto do link do HELP sem tradução:

=> [**Títulos e links traduzidos**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6886/357)

[Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

[How do I write a good answer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

[<s>How to reference material written by others</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

[What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

[How do I delete my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

[How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

[Why have I been limited to one question per week?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited)

<sub>*EXTRA: Este link foi encontrado na lista de privilégios, não sei se sua tradução é tão relevante quanto os outros, mas fica aí registrado também.*</sub>

[Access To Site Analytics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

---

Sei que há o transifex para quem quiser ajudar, mas como não domino inglês a nível suficiente de fazer tais traduções, deixo as sugestões pra quem quiser a iniciativa :)

Outra coisa, o link para a página *be-nice* em [help/nosso-modelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/stackexchange) está duplicado (há um link *be-nice* e outro *Seja Respeitoso* direcionando para a mesma página).

> Quem quiser ir atualizando os textos, pode postar como resposta wiki aqui mesmo e informar o link do qual aquele texto corresponde a tradução, isso facilita ao  Juan M♦ identificar e efetuar a alteração na página.

Comment: Excelente trabalho diegofm

Comment: @JorgeB. obrigado :) Já que não posso(ainda) colaborar diretamente com as traduções, essa é foi a forma que encontrei para contribuir com quem traduz, já adianta muita coisa.

Comment: Não encontrei no Transifex.

Comment: @Articunohexacampão Este tópico ainda está ativo? É possível colaborar com traduções?

Answer (score 12):

Muito obrigado, diegofm!

> **Aviso:** O post é longo, mas é uma explicação de como e porque as coisas funcionam do jeito que funcionam. Pode pular pra parte final, se quiser uma humilde sugestão do que podemos fazer com o que temos no momento.

Eu sei nos últimos tempos, venho tocando nesse ponto frequentemente, mas a Central de Ajuda é um dos [problemas que precisamos resolver](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4996), só não temos muita certeza de como. Existem complicações técnicas, e uma série de expectativas erradas, que atrapalharam a manutenção da Central de Ajuda na nossa língua.

Antes do SOpt abrir, tudo do site (incluindo a Central de Ajuda) foi enviado à uma empresa de tradução e a expectativa é de que, como esses artigos não são alterados com frequência, bastava ficar de olho nas alterações eventuais e aplicá-las por conta própria. Eu (e cada CM internacional, em seus respectivos sites) ficaria responsável por isso, e tudo correria bem.

Só que, como praticamente tudo que a gente imaginava *antes* de abrir os sites... Isso não era verdade. Há, em média, 2 artigos alterados e 2 novos artigos, por mês e nós não temos nenhum sistema de "alerta" de quando essas mudanças ocorrem. Junte à isso o fato de que traduzir a Ajuda, com textos longos ao invés de strings avulsas, dá muito mais trabalho do que a interface do site, e é a receita pra negligência.

O ideal, em casos assim, seria poder contar com a ajuda de todo mundo, mas os artigos da Central são guardados no banco de dados e não podemos usar o Transifex. Pelo menos não sem fazer alguma adaptação em como geramos as strings a serem enviadas. E isso requer recursos.

Também não podemos dar acesso direto aos artigos, sem passar pelo mesmo tipo de crivo que o Transifex permite. Mas criar um mecanismo que permita essa revisão *também* requer recursos.

## Parte Final

Atualmente, eu não tenho muitas ideias de como contornar essa situação. O trabalho de catalogação do [@diegofm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/28595/diegofm) é um **excelente** primeiro passo. Minha ideia favorita é criar uma série de posts no Meta (como Wiki), com a versão atual do artigo em Inglês, e contar com a ajuda de vocês para traduzi-los. Não seriam todos de uma vez só, cada novo post aparece à medida em que o anterior for traduzido.

Quando a tradução estiver finalizada, eu coloco a nossa versão no ar e a gente passa pro próximo.

O que acham?

Comment: Gabe e se houver uma alteração, passa tudo de novo para inglês e tem de se vir ao meta editar e colocar de novo a versão em português?

Comment: E eu imaginando que todos os textos estavam no transifex. Mas gostei da idéia. Assim fica mais fácil dos texto serem localizados para tradução.

Comment: Concordo com a ideia dos posts em série do tipo Wiki/comunitário para cada página, pode ser tudo dentro de uma mesma pergunta ao meu ver.

Comment: Eu apoio essa ideia.

Comment: @VictorStafusa No momento, eu estou mais inclinado à criar um projeto no Github. Tenho estudado a nossa Central de Ajuda há umas 2 semanas, pra ver qual a melhor maneira de resolver o problema e espero ter alguma notícia em breve.

Comment: @Articuno Avançemos com esta sugestão original. Esses artigos não estão na Transifex, então eu precisarei trocá-los manualmente depois de receber as traduções. Isso não será um problema.

Comment: @JuanM as traduções serão publicadas como resposta wiki nesta pergunta, a medida em que quem quiser colaborar for traduzindo.

Answer (score 6):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

[The Community user deleted my question! What gives?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba)

## O usuário Comunidade apagou minha pergunta! O que acontece?

[O usuário Comunidade](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19738) irá apagar automaticamente perguntas antigas abandonadas/mortas nas seguintes circunstâncias:

**Se a pergunta tem mais de `30` dias, e ...**

- possui pontuação -1 ou menos
- não possui respostas
- não está bloqueada

**... ou ...**

foi fechada e migrada para um sítio diferente

**...ou...**

foi migrada a partir de um sítio diferente, e depois [rejeitada](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)

... ela será apagada automaticamente. Essas são denominadas perguntas "mortas" (`RemoveDeadQuestions`, `RemoveMigrationStubs` no caso de uma migração ou `RemoveRejectedMigrations` no caso de uma migração rejeitada).

**Se a pergunta tem mais de `365` dias, e ...**

- possui uma pontuação de 0 ou menos, **ou** uma pontuação de 1 e um dono apagado
- não possui respostas
- não está bloqueada
- possui contagem de visualizações <= a idade da pergunta em dias vezes 1.5
- possui 1 ou 0 comentários
- não está em um site Meta

...ela será automaticamente apagada. Essas são denominadas perguntas "abandonadas" (`RemoveAbandonedQuestions`).

Essas checagens são executadas semanalmente em todos os sítios.

**Se a pergunta foi fechada há mais de `9` dias, e ...**

- não foi fechada como duplicata
- possui uma pontuação de 0 ou menos
- não está bloqueada
- não possui respostas com pontuação > 0
- não possui resposta aceita
- não possui votos de reabertura pendentes
- não foi editada nos últimos 9 dias

...ela será automaticamente apagada. Estas são "fechadas abandonadas", e são denominadas como `RemoveAbandonedClosed`.

Esta checagem é feita diariamente em todos os sítios.

Veja também: A meta-postagem oficial do FAQ ["Como funciona a remoção? O que pode fazer uma postagem ser apagada, e o que isso significa realmente?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

> [Como eu reporto assédios?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment)

## Como eu reporto assédios?

O Stack Overflow tenta proporcionar aos seus usuários um ambiente onde eles se sintam confortáveis. Como tal, não toleramos o assédio em nossos sites e levamos a sério os relatórios de assédio.

### O que constitui o assédio?

Nossa [política de seja respeitoso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) se aplica em todos os nossos sites.

Os comportamentos sistemáticos e / ou continuados que afligem ou degradam alguém de uma forma que faria com que uma pessoa razoável temesse por sua segurança ou a segurança daqueles que os cercam constituem o assédio. Seguir um usuário ou um grupo de usuários, on-line ou off-line, até o ponto em que comecem a se sentir que não é seguro publicar on-line ou temem que sua segurança também é um assédio.

### Ok, estou sendo assediado; o que eu faço?

Use o nosso [formulário de contato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) e escolha "Outro". Tente ser tão específico e claro quanto possível, e forneça links para postagens relevantes, comentários, mensagens de bate-papo, etc. Recomendamos que você também os [sinalize](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), se você quiser se certificar de que eles são removidos e / ou tratados mais rapidamente - ainda olharemos mesmo que um moderador já tenha tomado medidas antes de analisarmos o seu relatório.

### O que acontece uma vez que eu envio um relatório?

Examinamos cada relatório individualmente, e você sempre receberá uma resposta de nossa parte, independentemente do resultado. Vamos dar uma olhada na sua mensagem e nos posts / comentários / mensagens relevantes mencionados e tentar reunir o máximo de contexto possível. Se determinarmos que os comportamentos relatados constituem, de fato, assédio, tomaremos medidas (que podem variar de aviso a suspensão do usuário).

### Você pode me dar informações de outro usuário?

De acordo com a nossa [Política de Privacidade](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy), não fornecemos informações do usuário, exceto conforme exigido pelo processo legal válido. Se você está trabalhando com a polícia ou seu advogado verifique com eles sobre os processos legais apropriados e corretos para obter essas informações. Se somos contactados diretamente pela aplicação da lei, trabalharemos com eles e os ajudaremos com a investigação.

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

[Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited)

## Por que o sistema está pedindo para eu esperar um dia ou mais antes de fazer outra pergunta?

Fazer perguntas pode ser complicado, e nós queremos que todos os nossos usuários tenham a melhor experiência possível no site. Você fez algumas perguntas, parte das quais não foi muito bem recebida pela comunidade; é hora de fazer uma pequena pausa e observar o site mais atentamente.

A melhor maneira de aproveitar este momento é olhar algumas das perguntas mais bem-votadas nas [tags](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags) que interessam a você, ordenando-as de acordo com o número de votos:

[image: escolhendo a aba "votos" na lista de perguntas de uma determinada tag]

Você irá perceber que essas perguntas têm algumas coisas em comum:

- Elas obedecem a gramática, o uso das maiúsculas e a pontuação tanto quanto a habilidade do autor permite;
- Elas definem um problema claro que necessita de solução e incluem todos os detalhes necessários para ilustrar o problema de uma maneira que outros possam reproduzí-lo;
- Elas possuem títulos claros e descritivos, geralmente na forma de uma pergunta;
- Elas vão direto ao ponto, são fáceis de ler e fáceis de entender.

Assim que você tiver passado um tempo olhando outras perguntas, volte para suas perguntas anteriores e edite-as a fim de melhorá-las. Também recomendamos que procure perguntas que você possa responder e forneça ótimas respostas para elas. Tome alguns momentos para se familiarizar com [o funcionamento da busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching); muitas perguntas foram feitas e respondidas no passado.

Se já não fez isso, por favor leia nossas recomendações sobre [como perguntar bem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), e os [tipos de perguntas que devem ser evitadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

***Este bloqueio é apenas temporário, mas bloqueios muito mais longos existem no sistema***. Estamos tentando reduzir o seu ritmo e lhe oferecer mais direcionamento agora, esperando que você evite um período muito mais longo sem o sistema permitir perguntas feitas com a sua conta. Por favor dedique um tempo a revisitar e melhorar as suas perguntas onde for possível.

Você será bem-vindo a fazer novas perguntas em breve, mas por favor certifique-se de pesquisar os seus problemas antes de perguntar, e pergunte somente quando você estiver realmente emperrado. Quando for preciso perguntar, procure seguir o direcionamento que fornecemos e assim a experiência de todos nós será muito melhor.

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

## O que significa beta?

Este site foi criado através de um [processo aberto e democrático](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) na [Área 51 da rede Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Sites criados através desse processo começam em "beta", significa que o site está sob definição e construção. Existem algumas diferenças entre sites beta e não beta em nossa rede:

- Todos os sites beta têm o mesmo design. Uma vez que o site não for mais beta, ele terá um design exclusivo criado com a contribuição da comunidade.
- Os [privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/privileges) têm seus valores reduzidos durante a fase beta para ajudar a garantir a governança da comunidade no início.
- No início do beta, a Stack Exchange [indica os moderadores](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) até o site se tornar grande o suficiente para sustentar uma [eleição democrática para moderadores](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3882).

Durante o beta, a comunidade trabalha junta para responder [sete questões essenciais](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) para cada site da Stack Exchange:

1. Questões sobre {assunto} estão dentro do escopo?
2. O que o nosso FAQ deve ter?
3. Como vamos classificar (taguear) questões sobre {assunto}?
4. Quem devem ser os moderadores?
5. Qual deve ser o slogan do nosso site?
6. Qual deve ser nosso logo e como o design deve ser?
7. Como nós vamos promover o site?

Não existe um período de tempo definido para que o site permaneça em beta; Será beta [pelo tempo necessário para atingir a audiência](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/), com avaliações periódicas para ajudar a comunidade a saber onde está e o que precisa de mais trabalho.

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

[What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts)

## O que deve conter um resumo wiki de tag?

Tags são o mapa de-facto dos tópicos permitidos (e implicitamente proibidos por omissão) em seu site. É por isso que as primeiras duas páginas das tags devem ter no mínimo excelentes resumos wiki de tag. Se puderem ter [wikis de tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) ótimos e completos, é ainda melhor, mas é preciso engatinhar antes de poder andar. Focar no resumo de ~500 caracteres é uma forma simples de começar - e esse texto aparece em um número de lugares no site, inclusive ao passar o mouse sobre as tags.

## Diretrizes para escrever resumos de tag úteis

**O resumo é o discurso de elevador da tag.** Você só tem ~500 caracteres de texto comum para o resumo, por isso não se sinta obrigado a cobrir tudo nele! Deixe isso para a wiki Markdown de tag de 30.000+ caracteres. O resumo deve definir a qualidade comum das perguntas contendo essa tag - reduzidas a algumas frases curtas.

**Evite definir genericamente o conceito por trás de uma tag,** a não ser que ela seja altamente especializada. A tag "email", por exemplo, não precisa explicar o que é um email. Acho que podemos assumir com segurança que a maioria dos usuários de internet sabe o que é email; não há valor em uma explicação boilerplate de email para ninguém.

**Concentre-se no que a tag significa para a sua comunidade.** Para "email" em Server Fault, mencione os aspectos de email relacionados a servidor, incluindo POP3, SMTP, IMAP e software de servidor. Para "email" em Super User, mencione clientes desktop de email e exclua explicitamente webmail, visto que isso seria mais apropriado para [http://webapps.stackexchange.com](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

**Forneça orientação básica sobre quando usar a tag.** Em outras palavras, quais tipos de perguntas deveriam ter essa tag? Tags só existem como formas de organizar perguntas, por isso se não fornecermos orientação adequada sobre quais questões precisam dessa tag, elas não chegarão a ser rotuladas, deixando o resumo da tag inutilizado. Pense nisso como um discurso de vendas: em uma sala cheia de tags gritando "me escolha!", o que convenceria a pessoa fazendo a pergunta a escolher a sua tag?

**Algumas tags são conhecimento comum.** A maioria das tags requer um pouco de explicação no resumo, mesmo que de apenas 3 ou 4 palavras. Mas se a tag é conhecimento comum - isto é, se você parasse qualquer pessoa na rua e dissesse a palavra da tag para ela e ela soubesse sobre o que você está falando - então não se preocupe em dar nenhuma explicação sobre a tag. Atenha-se no resumo ao uso corrente da tag pela comunidade.

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

[How to not be a spammer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

## Como não ser um spammer

Aqui a comunidade tende a negativar autopromoção gratuita e sinalizar como spam. Poste respostas boas e relevantes, e se acontecer de alguma vez ser sobre seu produto ou site, não tem problema. No entanto você deve mencionar sua relação com o produto/site em suas respostas.

Aqui estão alguns comportamentos que devem ser evitados - mesmo com as melhores intenções, estes vão quase sempre resultar em uma sinalização de spam:

- **Não fale muito sobre seu produto / site / livro / trabalho**. Pessoas em geral vão ler suas respostas baseadas nas próprias habilidades de resolver problemas; Se você não for bom nisso, então elas vão achar mais interessante quem é você e no que você está trabalhando. Se você responder perguntas onde o conteúdo é apenas propaganda, os usuários vão assumir que você está aqui apenas para vender algo.
- **Não diga - mostre!** A melhor maneira para evitar ser visto como vendedor de oléo de cobra é demonstrar a solução do que simplesmente afirmar que o problema pode ser resolvido.
- **Não adicione links exceto para dar suporte ao que você já escreveu**. Links não são substitutos para incluir informação em suas respostas, e um link deve sempre ter uma relação direta com uma parte da sua resposta. Veja também: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Se você está aqui para oferecer suporte ao seu produto, por favor veja: [Posso oferecer suporte ao meu produto nesse site?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Aqui estão algumas dicas para escrever respostas bem recebidas:

- **Sempre resolva o problema do autor da pergunta**. Uma boa resposta deve no minimo permitir que o autor da pergunta resolva seu problema. Nem todas as perguntas podem ser respondidas dessa forma mas se você acha que não pode escrever uma solução completa então é melhor procurar outra pergunta.
- **Responda para o futuro**. Se você quer que as pessoas vejam o seu trabalho de forma positiva, escreva com o objetivo de responder não apenas ao problema do autor da pergunta, mas também os problemas que provavelmente terão aqueles que encontrem a pergunta no futuro. Em particular, sempre explique por que a solução que você está apresentando é apropriada e como ela funciona - isso pode permitir que outros com problemas muito semelhantes aprendam a resolvê-los, mesmo quando não são cópias do que você está respondendo.
- **Evite perguntas mal elaboradas**. Postar uma resposta bem escrita para uma pergunta mal elaborada apenas faz sua resposta parecer pior. Também se familiarize com [o que está no escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e evite responder perguntas sobre assuntos não bem vistos.

Para mais informações, veja [como escrever uma boa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Se você está aqui apenas para vender algo ou direcionar tráfego para seu site, então por favor evite postar respostas. Nossas taxas de publicidade são bastante razoáveis; entre em contato com setor de vendas para mais detalhes. Nós também oferecemos anúncios gratuitos de comunidade para projetos de código aberto e organizações sem fins lucrativos.

Answer (score 5):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

**O que é um post bloqueado?**

Um post que foi "bloqueado" não pode ser alterado de maneira nenhuma. O bloqueio impede...

- ... votação no post (incluindo votos de fechamento/reabertura em perguntas)
- ... edições
- ... Comentários
- ... respostas (no caso de perguntas)
- ... sinalizações (A opção "precisa de atenção dos moderadores" ainda é permitida, exceto no caso de Significância histórica - veja abaixo)

Quem pode bloquear um post?

[Moderadores](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators) podem aplicar tipos especificos de bloqueios em perguntas e respostas.

O [sistema também pode bloquear posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) em algumas situações:

- Se o post for deletado por sinalicações de ["Rude ou abusivo"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).
- Se o post for migrado para outro site.
- Se o post foi migrado para o site atual e foi [rejeitado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work).
- Se uma pergunta foi mesclada com outra, as repostas serão movidas e a pergunta de origem será bloqueada.

Por quanto tempo dura o bloqueio?

Depende do motivo pelo qual o bloqueio teve início.

- Quando o moderador bloqueia um post ele é obrigado a informar a duração de tempo. As opções são: 1 hora, 1 dia, 1 semana e permanente.
  Ao final do periodo, o sistema irá automáticamente desbloquear o post.
- Quando o sistema bloqueia um post ele fica bloqueado por tempo indeterminado - somente um moderador pode desbloqueá-lo.

Um moderador pode manualmente debloquear uma postagem a qualquer momente que achar necessário.

**Quando um post deve ser bloqueado?**

Como regra geral, bloqueios temporários devem ser usados sempre que as modificações em um post estiverem causando sérios problemas no site. Por exemplo:

- [edit wars](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/03/04/the-great-edit-wars/)
- Brigas prolongadas em comentários (mas veja [guia de moderação em comentários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments))
- Um post controverso que está em discussão sobre meta

Bloqueios permanentes quase sempre não devem ser aplicados, com a exceção dos impostos pelo sistema. Existem duas exceções:

1. Um pergunta extremamente popular a qual agora é considerada inapropriada para o site pode ser bloqueada por "significância histórica": Isto modifica a aparência da pergunta, automaticamente bloqueia todas as respostas e desativa sinalizações por completo. Esse bloqueio deve ser reservado para casos em que um artefato cultural estimado seria excluído; **não use** para qualquer outra finalidade.
2. Um "wiki" é uma pergunta cujas respostas podem ser editadas por usuários de baixa reputação, atribuídas a vários autores e não concedem reputação ao autor original. Ocasionalmente, são úteis nos casos em que as informações devem ser compiladas por vários autores (por exemplo, uma lista de recursos ou documentação do próprio site); nesses casos, bloquear a pergunta impede que ela seja fechada e impede que outras respostas sejam adicionadas.

Veja também:

- [O que é um post "bloqueado"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post) no Meta Stack Exchange.
- [O que é um bloqueio histórico, e para que serve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for) no Meta Stack Exchange
- [Opções avançadas de busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 3):

## Páginas apenas com o texto do link do HELP sem tradução:

[Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Por que algumas perguntas estão marcadas como duplicadas?

duplicates --> duplicadas

[How do I write a good answer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Como escrever uma boa resposta?

how-to-answer --> como-responder

[<s>How to reference material written by others</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

[What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)

O que fazer se eu vir alguém fazendo algo ruim?

flagging --> sinalizando

[How do I delete my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

Como eu apago minha conta?

deleting-account --> apagando-conta

[How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

Como eu adiciono ou removo credenciais de login a partir da minha conta?

edit-credentials --> editar-credenciais

[I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Criei acidentalmente duas contas; como faço para mesclá-las?

merging-accounts --> mesclando-contas

[Why have I been limited to one question per week?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited)

Por que fui limitado a uma pergunta por semana?

question-limited --> pergunta-limitado

<sub>*EXTRA: Este link foi encontrado na lista de privilégios, não sei se sua tradução é tão relevante quanto os outros, mas fica aí registrado também.*</sub>

[Access To Site Analytics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics)

Acesso à Análise do Site

site-analytics --> análise-site

Answer (score 2):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

> [What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags)

---

## O que são sinalizações rejeitadas, e o que devo fazer a respeito?

### O que é uma sinalização rejeitada?

"Rejeitada" significa que moderadores (ou outros usuários confiáveis do site) decidiram não tomar ação em relação a uma [sinalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) que você fez em face a um problema que você observou.

### Por que uma das minhas sinalizações foi rejeitada?

Há vários motivos para uma sinalização ser rejeitada:

- Outros podem discordar e achar que o problema que você identificou não existe (por exemplo, você sugeriu que uma pergunta deveria ser fechada por estar fora do escopo, mas a pergunta está dentro dos tópicos aceitos pelo site).
- Pode ser um problema que você mesmo poderia ter lidado (por exemplo, você sinalizou uma resposta incorreta, quando você poderia ter dado um voto negativo ou corrigido com uma edição).
- O problema pode ter sido resolvido no momento em que a sua sinalização foi verificada (por exemplo, o autor da pergunta editou-a depois da sua sinalização).
- O problema pode ser sutil, e quem revisou a sinalização simplesmente não conseguiu percebê-lo (por exemplo, você sinalizou como abusivo uma tentativa de [rickroll](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ), mas o moderador que verificou a sinalização não clicou no link).
- Geralmente os moderadores darão um motivo para rejeitar a sinalização. Você pode vê-lo visitando o [seu histórico de sinalizações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current).

### O que devo fazer se uma das minhas sinalizações for rejeitada?

Você não precisa fazer nada, mas se o problema ainda persiste, talvez você queira fazer algo. Dito isso...

1. Tente entender por qual motivo a sinalização foi rejeitada (veja acima). Talvez quem a verificou tenha deixado passar algum detalhe... Ou talvez você que não tenha percebido tais detalhes, e esta é uma oportunidade de aprender com isso.
2. Visite a pergunta/resposta ou comentário que você sinalizou e veja se o problema permanece. Se a questão foi resolvida ou se não tem mais importância, você pode deixar para lá.

Se o problema ainda persiste, pense em outras maneiras de você mesmo resolvê-lo:

- [Dar um voto negativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) é o suficiente para alertar os demais sobre o problema?
- Você consegue [editar o post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing) corrigindo o problema, ao mesmo tempo em que respeita as intenções do autor?

Se você mesmo pode resolver o problema, não há motivo para sinalizar - apenas resolva!

Se o problema é algo que você não consegue resolver sozinho, e você acha que ele foi negligenciado, então você pode sinalizá-lo com a opção "precisa de atenção dos moderadores", explicando o problema em detalhes: isso permite que você dê uma descrição mais precisa, indicando os detalhes mais sutis que não foram vistos por aqueles que verificaram sua primeira sinalização.

Nos casos em que sua sinalização foi rejeitada por discordância entre você e aqueles que a verificaram, você pode [abrir uma discussão no meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/): lá você tem a chance de apresentar a situação para toda a comunidade, e possivelmente persuadi-los a mudar as regras sobre o que é permitido e apropriado. Não tenha pressa em escrever tal proposta, e apresente exemplos explicando como as mudanças que você gostaria de ver poderiam melhorar o site para todos.

### O que acontece se muitas sinalizações minhas são rejeitadas?

Se algumas de suas sinalizações são rejeitadas, você poderá ver um aviso dizendo para visitar seu histórico de sinalizações e revisá-las. Isso te dará a oportunidade de colocar o conselho acima em prática.

Se pelo menos um quarto de 10 ou mais sinalizações forem rejeitadas nos últimos 7 dias, você será temporariamente impedido de sinalizar. Este banimento dura até 7 dias, depois dos quais você poderá sinalizar novamente; esperamos que você aproveite este período para revisar suas sinalizações seguindo as orientações acima, e volte melhor informado. Lembre-se, são pessoas como você que fazem tudo isso funcionar - então quanto melhor trabalharmos juntos para resolver problemas, melhor o Stack Overflow em Português será para todos!

### Veja também

- [O privilégio de Sinalizar Posts](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)
- [Por que sinalizações marcadas como útil/rejeitada nem sempre estão relacionadas com ações da moderação?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105391/why-does-flag-marking-as-helpful-declined-not-always-correlate-with-moderator-ac)
- [Como eu posso usar a sinalização "Não é uma resposta" de maneira adequada?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)
- [Como sair do banimento de sinalizações](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/)

Answer (score 2):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

> [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

---

## Mudei de ideia com relação a minha pergunta; posso removê-la?

Você pode mudar de ideia sobre as coisas que postou. Talvez você não queira que seus colegas de trabalho vejam aquela pergunta específica sobre procura de emprego, ou você percebeu que não deveria ter colocado código proprietário, ou você não quer que seus amigos vejam aquele erro besta na sua pergunta. **Se ninguém respondeu ainda, vá em frente e [apague-a](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) - ninguém se incomodará**.

Porém, se sua pergunta já tem respostas boas, não é justo que estas sejam removidas junto com a pergunta: outras pessoas se esforçaram para te ajudar e mesmo que você não precise mais das respostas, alguém pode precisar. É por isso que o sistema te impede de remover perguntas já respondidas, na maior parte das vezes.

Mas há algumas outras coisas que você pode fazer:

- Se sua pergunta é desnecessariamente específica, **edite-a** e deixe-a mais genérica. Você realmente precisa dizer o nome das empresas envolvidas, ou outros detalhes do tipo? Sua localização é importante? Você pode deixar o código mais genérico e renomear algumas variáveis? Não invalide as respostas existentes e não torne a pergunta vaga demais a ponto de se tornar impossível de ser respondida, mas se você poderia ser alguma das milhares de pessoas que possivelmente teriam feito aquela pergunta, provavelmente ninguém saberá que foi você. **Em quase todos os casos, editar é tudo que precisa ser feito**.
- Se você não consegue ver um jeito de recuperar a pergunta removendo esses detalhes específicos, e nenhuma das respostas está com muitos votos positivos, e principalmente se a pergunta está fechada, você pode sinalizar e pedir que a moderação apague-a. Se não há muito a perder, eles poderão fazer isso para você.
- Se você colocou informações muito sensíveis, como uma senha ou uma chave de API, edite a pergunta removendo estas informações, e sinalize para a moderação, pedindo para que **removam-nas** do histórico de edições. Seja específico ao descrever o que precisa ser removido e o motivo (caso não seja óbvio). Estes pedidos de remoção devem ser aprovados por dois moderadores, então haverá uma certa demora. Se a pergunta está fechada, os moderadores podem decidir por simplesmente apagá-la. Veja [este post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327145) para informações mais específicas sobre como preparar um post para este tipo de remoção, sem prejudicar a pergunta ou suas respostas.
- Se a pergunta é boa, não há informações sensíveis nela e o problema é apenas o fato de ter seu nome associado a ela, você pode desassociá-la de sua conta. Não chega a ser um anonimato completo; qualquer coisa que você escreve na internet vive para sempre em algum lugar. Os pedidos são revisados, o que pode levar algum tempo. Se seu pedido for aprovado, não poderá ser revertido depois.

Embora a remoção de informações sensíveis e desassociação sejam permitidos, eles são feitos para serem exceções, e não ações rotineiras. Se você mantiver um padrão de postar de forma imprudente e depois pedir por remoção ou desassociação, por várias vezes seguidas, isso poderá resultar em suspensão. Escreva como se tudo que você posta fosse ficar publicamente visível para sempre.

Vandalizar ou remover excessivamente posts úteis pode acionar um alerta do sistema e uma ação imediata da moderação. Por favor tenha respeito com o esforço alheio: evite invalidar o trabalho dos outros e criar incômodo.

**Nada disso pode ser usado para sair de um bloqueio do sistema** — se você está bloqueado para fazer novas perguntas ou respostas, por favor leia [Por que não posso mais fazer perguntas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) e [Por que as respostas não são mais aceitas da minha conta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans), para saber como sair do bloqueio.

Answer (score 2):

> [What browsers do we support?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support)

---

## Quais navegadores são suportados?

O Stack Overflow suporta as duas últimas versões estáveis dos principais navegadores. Isso não inclui versões beta/dev, que não são suportadas.

Os navegadores suportados podem ser [visualizados](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/) usando nossa string de configuração do [Browserslist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist).

Se o seu navegador não estiver nesta lista, ele ainda poderá funcionar, mas com uma experiência degradada.

Comment: traduzi `support` para compatível.. mas não tenho certeza, podem sugerir mudanças.

Answer (score 1):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

Páginas que só precisam da tradução do título:

- [Manifesto of Stack Overflow in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto)

  - Tradução: **Manifesto do Stack Overflow em Português**
- [How do I delete my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account)

  - Tradução: **Como eu apago minha conta?**
- [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials)

  - Tradução: **Como adicionar ou remover log-ins na minha conta?**
- [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

  - Tradução: **Criei duas contas por acidente; como posso mesclá-las?**
- [Why have I been limited to one question per week?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited)

  - Tradução: **Por que estou limitado a fazer uma pergunta por semana?**

Answer (score 1):

[status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto)

> [What is Flair?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flair)

---

## O que é *Flair*?

*Flair* é uma imagem que resume sua participação no site (sua reputação, suas medalhas, os sites que você mais participa), adequada para colocar no seu *website* ou imprimir e pendurar na sua roupa, [se você preferir](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KJtrLKGZZFg).

### Exemplo:

[image]

Para mais informações, logue na sua conta e vá na seção "Flair" do [seu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current).

Answer (score 0):

> [Who are the staff, and what is their role
> here?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/staff)

---

## Quem são os funcionários e qual é o papel deles aqui?

Os funcionários são pessoas empregadas pela Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange, Inc.) para vários fins. Estes são cargos pagos, não voluntários. Embora os membros mais visíveis da equipe geralmente sejam os das nossas equipes de gerenciamento de comunidade e plataforma pública, esses são um pequeno subconjunto da equipe que mantém essa plataforma funcionando.

Como posso identificar um membro funcionário?

Os funcionários se enquadram em uma de duas categorias, com diferentes indicadores:

- Funcionário geral: Esses membros representam a maior parte de nossos funcionários. Eles são usuários regulares em sua maior parte. Se você vir um deles em nossos meta sites, um rótulo de "Funcionário" será exibido ao lado do nome de usuário em suas postagens e comentários. Eles também têm um rótulo de "Funcionário" em sua página de perfil em sites meta e não meta.
- Funcionário diamante: Um pequeno subconjunto de nossa equipe – geralmente os desenvolvedores, engenheiros e membros comunitários – possuem acesso especial a ferramentas e conteúdo de moderação. Eles são mais visíveis e exibem um losango (♦) ao lado de seu nome de usuário, assim como moderadores eleitos do site; em meta sites, os rótulos "Funcionário" e "♦ Mod" aparecerão ao lado de seus nomes de usuário. Além disso, os rótulos "Funcionário" e "♦ Moderador" são exibidos em sua página de perfil em sites meta e não meta.

Comment: Fiquei em dúvida qual soa melhor `Os staff se enquadram...` ou `Os staffs se enquadram` mas creio que não há prejuízo no entendimento.

Comment: Staff não é um termo técnico ou uma palavra sem tradução, em português o podemos traduzir como `funcionário`, logo tem plural. A palavra equipe (que também pode ser uma tradução) não me parece soar bem para o caso especifico. Para não haver confusão, employer pode ficar como empregado. Observação: provavelmente a tag que ainda aparece como Staff nos perfis deverá ser traduzida em https://pt.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Staff, assim como foi feito com a string Moderator: https://pt.traducir.win/strings/7798

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu acabei não traduzindo porque quando eu clico em um usuário que possui alguma das tags indicadas (ou as duas) esses são os termos que aparecem ao ver o perfil, então se for traduzido poderia induzir algúem ao erro ao acessar algum perfil de mod ou staff e não ver exatamente o que está no texto.

Comment: Então, como lhe expliquei no primeiro comentário, as tags nos perfis ainda aparecem como staff porque não foram traduzidas, mas a string existe, assim como existe a `moderator`, que foi traduzida, feita a tradução nas tags fica tudo alinhado. O problema é que de tempos em tempos mudam a estrutura do site, então temos que traduzir novamente no `traducir.win`

Answer (score 0):

> [When does Stack Exchange ask for my cookie consent?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/cookie-reconsent)

---

## Quando o Stack Exchange solicita meu consentimento de cookie?

*A Stack Exchange nunca vendeu e nunca venderá seus dados pessoais a terceiros. Se você quiser saber mais, consulte [nossa política de privacidade](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy).*

O Stack Exchange solicita seu consentimento para os cookies não essenciais que usamos em três circunstâncias:

1. Pedimos consentimento **se for sua primeira visita ao site** (ou se você ainda não selecionou suas preferências de consentimento de cookies). Até que você faça uma seleção de consentimento, seu consentimento continuará sendo solicitado.
2. Pedimos consentimento **se já passou um ano desde que você fez suas seleções de cookies**. Para garantir que suas configurações de consentimento estejam atualizadas e de acordo com as leis de proteção de dados aplicáveis, pedimos que você confirme suas configurações de consentimento uma vez por ano.
3. Pedimos consentimento **se tivermos feito alterações materiais em nossa política de cookies** desde a última vez que você fez seleções de consentimento. É importante ressaltar que, se adicionarmos um *novo* cookie ou se a forma como usamos um cookie atual mudar significativamente, solicitaremos seu consentimento novamente.

Observação: *certos complementos do navegador, como bloqueadores de pop-up, podem interferir em nossa capacidade de salvar suas preferências de cookies. Se você tiver esse complemento, poderá ver um prompt de consentimento de cookie em todas as páginas.*

Suas configurações de consentimento controlam quais cookies não essenciais o Stack Exchange pode armazenar. Incentivamos você a revisar [nossa política de cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/cookie-policy), que é o local onde descrevemos quais cookies definimos e como eles são usados.