# As páginas do Help tem conteudo "estático" ou usaram o "markdown"?

Tags: debate

Sei que a pergunta parece estranha, após ler [esta questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5316/3635) e a resposta do *@Gabe* fiquei se me perguntando se o conteúdo+HTML são estáticos, pois seria interessante liberar em um repositório (no Github ou bitbucket por exemplo) apenas a parte do conteúdo, não tenho certeza quanto a maioria, mas eu poderia dedicar um tempo a traduzir e adaptar os textos.

Não sou tão bom no inglês, mas na escrita e entendimento do sentido de uma frase e até algumas expressões do idioma eu tenho facilidade em adaptar.

Pode ser que não seja tão rápido, mas sendo apenas texto+html acho que no máximo 1 mês e meio eu conseguiria traduzir tudo e sendo em um repositório aberto (claro que sem "conteúdo sensível") poderia mais de uma pessoa trabalhar a tradução, eu só não sei se isso seria possível de ser *"adaptado"* ao transefix.

Se acaso for um markdown poderíamos criar (assim como o [@Gabe está aparentemente planejando](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5318/3635)) deixar em respostas do tipo *wiki* e editaríamos elas até corrigir todas, acho que o @diegofm já enumerou tudo (quase) o que é **metade** do serviço.

Eu entendo que tem uma série de limitações e/ou conflitos que devem ser analisados antes de implementar uma ideia assim, devido ao transefix e cuidados com conteúdos sensíveis, mas deixo aqui como sugestões.

Answer (score 3):

Alguns dos artigos da ajuda tem HTML, mas nada que não possa ser facilmente convertido pra Markdown (negritos, listas, linhas, etc). Pelo menos nada que eu já tenha visto, e eu já editei basicamente todos os artigos pelo menos uma vez. Eu mesmo já converti uma série deles de HTML pra Markdown.

Eu gosto da ideia do repositório (talvez até mais do que a ideia de posts no Meta). Mas nunca parei pra pensar mais à fundo sobre como ela funcionaria. O meu ponto contra mais importante, que era a exigência de conhecimento de git pra poder participar da tradução, não é mais um problema desde que o Github introduziu a [edição online de arquivos](https://help.github.com/articles/editing-files-in-your-repository/).

Usar um repositório não vai resolver *todos* os problemas (sincronização dos dados e saber quando algo novo surgiu na Ajuda continuam sendo um problema), mas acho que pode ser um excelente caminho.

O que acham?

Comment: A mim parece-me boa ideia e talvez a devesses levar também aos devs, com um bocado de jeito conseguia-se que fosse utilizado para traduzir e para o site diretamente. Pensado assim muito em grande, talvez até para a rede toda.

Comment: @JorgeB. Não há necessidade pra rede toda (exceto Internacionais, claro). Os textos em inglês são criados e mantidos por nós mesmos sem maiores problemas. A Central de Ajuda é especificamente um lugar onde queremos total controle editorial, para garantir uniformidade de teor e tom da mensagem. As comunidades internacionais seriam um caso bem particular, o que não significa que não valha a pena o esforço de desenvolvimento pra integrar com uma solução externa - como essa de repositório.

Comment: Gabe foi só uma ideia para facilitar de saber quando fossem alterados os textos.

Comment: @JorgeB. Eu acho uma boa ideia. Apenas quis comentar sobre o potencial dela de ser utilizada em toda a rede.