# Lidar com sinalizadores?

Tags: suporte, moderação, privilégios

Na pagina relativa a privilégios de [Acesso Às Ferramentas Do Moderador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) diz:

> Os usuários que não têm o privilégio de voto pelo encerramento podem
>   pedir que sejam encerradas perguntas por meio de sinalização. Além
>   disso, todos os usuários podem sinalizar respostas para solicitar sua
>   exclusão.
>
> Esses sinalizadores serão exibidos na [lista de publicações sinalizadas
>   em suas ferramentas do moderador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged). No entanto, você não poderá ver quem
>   colocou cada sinalizador.

Porém, o tal link de publicações sinalizadas nas ferramentas de moderador redireciona para a página de análise, que eu já tinha acesso desde os 3k de rep.

Além do mais, grande parte do que é explicado em **Lidar com sinalizadores**, não consegui achar nenhuma página onde aquela explicação fosse aplicável.

Seria caso de texto desatualizado (talvez as ferramentas mudaram com o tempo) ou é algo que eu não estou sabendo acessar?

Answer (score 4):

Lembra [disso aqui?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5318/)

> Eu sei nos últimos tempos, venho tocando nesse ponto frequentemente, mas a Central de Ajuda é um dos problemas que precisamos resolver, só não temos muita certeza de como. Existem complicações técnicas, e uma série de expectativas erradas, que atrapalharam a manutenção da Central de Ajuda na nossa língua.

Você pode ver que a [página do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) sobre ferramentas de moderação está **bem** diferente da nossa. Isso porque, desde dezembro/2013, o original sofreu alterações ao longo do tempo, uma das maiores sendo justamente sobre a parte de sinalizações (removida em abril/2014).

Estou traduzindo-a novamente, e vou atualizar aqui quando estiver pronto.

PS: Eu trabalhei numa ferramenta que permitisse a participação da comunidade na manutenção da Central de Ajuda por cerca de 2 meses ano passado, mas depois precisei mudar de foco por um bom tempo... Meu plano é voltar a trabalhar nele até o fim de janeiro.

Espero resolver as complicações de segurança e confiabilidade que estava enfrentando ano passado, e poder atualizar vocês com boas novas.

## Atualização

Novo artigo na central de ajuda sobre [ferramentas de moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), fresquinho saído do forno.

Comment: Fico feliz de ver que era um caso de atualização da pagina mesmo, estava me sentindo meio burrinho por não entender porque o tal link não era acessivel apesar do texto da a entender que era.

Comment: @diegofm Burrinho é a gente da SE que tem 3 anos que não resolve isso....

Comment: Muito bom Gabe! =) só os últimos 2 links que precisam corrigir, acho que faltou o dominio(pt.stackoverflow.com) neles. Na última frase também tem um suposto link com markdown que não foi reconhecido.

Comment: @diegofm Valeu pelos toques. Tudo acertado.