# Textos não traduzidos na ajuda avançada de formatação de respostas

Tags: bug, tradução

Ao iniciar o desenvolvimento de uma resposta, fui ver a ajuda avançada de formatação e percebi que há alguns textos não traduzidos, como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Relacionada: [Traduções de páginas e links da “Central de Ajuda”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-p%C3%A1ginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda)