# Tradução errada na página de comportamento

Tags: bug, tradução

Eu prometi que ia ajudar no Transifex, mas só lembrei de me cadastrar hoje e ainda não fui aceito na equipe. Então, por enquanto, vou relatar uma pendência de tradução por aqui.

A página com as normas de conduta está com o título em inglês.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Sugiro como tradução:

> Que tipo de comportamento é esperado dos usuários?

Comment: Infelizmente, as páginas do /help não estão no transifex.

Comment: Relacionada: [Traduções de páginas e links da “Central de Ajuda”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5316/28595)

Comment: @renan You were accepted to the Transifex team the same day you requested membership.  Please let me know if you are still not able to log in to see the translation strings.

Comment: @JuanM thank you. I'll start helping right away.

Comment: @LINQ como podemos fazer para colocá-las lá?

Comment: @Renan infelizmente não tem como, isso fica a cargo dos devs do projeto.

Comment: Let me take a look at this and I'll report what I find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed and is [now live](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Thank you for your patience.

---

Isso foi corrigido e agora está [ao vivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Obrigado pela sua paciência.

Comment: Please, if possible, check the link I posted below the question. Gabe had said he would look at that case that I  had documented from several pages without translation. These pages listed in the link don`t have a transifex string too.

Comment: @Articuno não sei se já há uma sugestão de tradução para essas páginas, mas se você estiver interessado em traduzi-las o mais rápido possível, recomendo publicar a tradução no Meta, facilitando assim o trabalho do CM. Então, ele pode copiá-lo diretamente para a Central de Ajuda.

Comment: @Articuno Posteci um comentário sobre a outra pergunta. Basicamente, eu precisarei atualizar essas traduções manualmente. Se a comunidade pode ajudar a traduzir os artigos para mim, posso fazer o resto.