# Texto mal/não traduzido no popover ao iniciar comentário

Tags: bug, tradução

[image: Popover de novo comentário]

A parte mal traduzida, que eu considero, é a palavra **clarificações**, sugiro alterar para **esclarecimentos**, que é mais comum.

E a parte não traduzida é o seguno parágrafo:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** code`. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5316/64969; eu acho que seria só sugerir essa tradição no transifex, mas nunca fiz isso