# Página de ajuda de formatação com vários trechos em inglês

Tags: bug, tradução

A [página de ajuda para formatação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) está com vários trechos do texto em inglês.

Seguindo a [tradição dos *freehand red circles* do metaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775), seguem alguns exemplos:

- Na seção de "Código e texto pré-formatado":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Na seção "Intervalos de código":

[image]

E em vários outros pontos da página, aparecem alguns trechos em inglês.

Comment: Relacionada [Traduções de páginas e links da “Central de Ajuda”](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5316/traduções-de-páginas-e-links-da-central-de-ajuda)

Comment: @Articuno Pelo que entendi, eu posso adicionar uma resposta na pergunta que vc linkou, informando o link da central de ajuda e a respectiva sugestão de tradução. É isso?