# Central de Ajuda: Páginas sem traduções

Tags: debate, tradução

Continuando um trabalho que já foi [iniciado anteriormente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5316/5878), conversando com o [Nicolas](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky) vimos duas opções para realizar as traduções:

1. Abrir perguntas aqui no Meta para cada página com o markdown atual, sugerir as traduções pelas respostas e quando definida solicitar à equipe da SE (Nicolas/Juan/etc) para efetuar a atualização;
2. Liberar até três páginas (limitação do sistema) para que os moderadores possam editar;

Como dificilmente temos mais de uma sugestão para tradução, geralmente é uma que vai se moldando com as sugestões, acredito que criar uma pergunta para cada página será desnecessário, então poderíamos seguir o mesmo padrão da pergunta supracitada e colocar a sugestão de cada página como resposta a esta pergunta. Assim que a tradução permanecer inerte, sem novas sugestões, atualizamos na Central de Ajuda.

**Se for sugerir alguma tradução nova, lembre-se de riscar na lista abaixo e adicionar o link para a resposta**.

---

## Perguntando

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7726/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>Why are some questions marked as duplicate?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6886/5878))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>Why is the system asking me to wait a day or more before asking another question?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6877/28595))
- [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) ([há uma discussão em andamento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7730/112052), sobre a possibilidade remover esta página)

## Nosso modelo

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What is Flair?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flair) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7733/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>Manifesto of Stack Overflow in Portuguese</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/manifesto) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7732/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>How to not be a spammer</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/promotion) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6884/28595))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>The Community user deleted my question! What gives?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6876/28595))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What if I see someone doing something bad?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/flagging) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6886/5878))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What should a tag wiki excerpt contain?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6882/28595))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What does "beta" mean?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-beta) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6878/28595))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>How do I report harassment?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/harassment) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6864/28595))

## Reputação e moderação

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What are declined flags, and what should I do about them?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/declined-flags) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7725/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>What is a locked post?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/locked-posts) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6935/28595))

## Respondendo

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>How do I write a good answer?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6886/5878))

## Minha conta

- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>How do I delete my account?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7732/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7732/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7732/112052))
- [status-pronto](/questions/tagged/status-pronto). [<s>Why have I been limited to one question per week?</s>](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-limited) ([Tradução](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7732/112052))

## Privilégios

- [25.000 - Access To Site Analytics](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) (inclusive nome da página na [lista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges))

Comment: Mas eu coloco a resposta aqui ou na pergunta original?

Comment: @hkotsubo Essa é uma boa pergunta haha Eu já tentei listar ali as que já possuem resposta, talvez seria o ideal manter todas as traduções em uma mesma pergunta, né?

Comment: Outro detalhe é que em alguns casos só falta traduzir o título, pois o texto todo já está em português. Nesse caso seria um exagero colocar uma resposta só para o título, não? :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Nesses casos pensei em gerar uma resposta só, tal como feito na outra pergunta

Comment: Estamos discutindo a ideia de se criar um repositório Git com todas as páginas e o pessoal conseguir contribuir com PRs.

Comment: Já falei com o Nicolas a respeito das páginas com traduções e ele irá utilizá-las para atualizar a central de ajuda.

Comment: Faz sentido existir a página "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta"? Pois o site não está mais em private beta, e o conteúdo que tem lá - no meu entendimento - poderia ser suprido pela página "como perguntar". Vale a pena abrir outra discussão no meta sobre isso?

Comment: @hkotsubo Acho que vale a discussão em uma pergunta, sim

Comment: Tá lá: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7730/112052

Comment: Só falta traduzir o "Flair", tem nome pra isso em português?

Comment: @hkotsubo Acho que dá para manter como "Flair", pois é o termo utilizado no próprio site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss/flair

Comment: Na [página de privilégios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) nem o link e nem a [página em si](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) do privilégio que exige 25000 de reputação estão traduzidos.