# Podemos remover a página "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" (Como fazer perguntas no Beta Privado) da Central de Ajuda?

Tags: debate, central-de-ajuda

Atualmente, na [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking), existe a página ["How to Ask Questions in Private Beta"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) (Como fazer perguntas no Beta Privado).

Esta página fazia sentido quando o site ainda estava na fase de Beta Privado, há cerca de 5 anos atrás (para quem não sabe, todo site da [rede Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) começa na [Área 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) e passa por algumas fases antes de virar "oficial", e o status do SOpt [já consta como "Lançado"](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-%20in-portugees), o que quer dizer que a fase de Beta Privado há muito se foi).

Inclusive as instruções que tem lá são bem específicas sobre o status que o site tinha na época:

> The tone and quality of the questions asked during this temporary private beta are critically important.
>
> If the private beta doesn't produce enough high quality expert level questions, it won’t proceed onward to the public beta

Em tradução livre:

> O tom e qualidade das perguntas feitas nesta fase temporária de beta privado são extremamente importantes.
>
> Se o beta privado não produzir perguntas suficientes com alta qualidade, não prosseguirá para a fase de beta público.

As orientações seguintes até que são úteis atualmente (como "*evite enquetes, pesquisas e perguntas como qual é o melhor livro sobre tal assunto*"), mas na minha opinião, todas elas já são cobertas por [outras páginas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) da Central de Ajuda, como por exemplo [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [A respeito de quais tópicos posso fazer perguntas aqui?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) e [Que tipos de perguntas devo evitar de fazer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), além do [Manual de como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/112052).

Por isso, dado que:

- Já temos bastante material de ajuda sobre como fazer perguntas;
- A fase de beta privado já se foi há muito tempo, e portanto orientações específicas que só valiam para aquela época não valem mais hoje;
- E as outras orientações que tem na página do beta privado já são melhor explicadas em outras páginas da Central de Ajuda;

Podemos remover a página ["How to Ask Questions in Private Beta"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta) (Como fazer perguntas no Beta Privado) da Central de Ajuda?

---

Como "bônus", a página está toda em inglês, e eliminando-a, seria uma a menos para traduzir...

Comment: Eu também não vejo muita utilidade em mantê-la.

Comment: Related on Meta SE: [“How to Ask Questions in Private Beta” is listed in every site’s help centre](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401)

Comment: Menos coisas pra confundir.